# In Flask, how do I prevent a route from being accessed unless another route has been visited first?

Tags: python, flask

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I'm working on a Flask web app that displays a list of items in a table. The user can select a row and hit a `Delete` button to delete the item. However, before the item is deleted from the database, the user is first routed to a confirmation screen where some item details are displayed as well as a `Confirm` button. The url for the confirmation page follows this pattern: `dashboard/confirm-delete/<id>` and the url for the actual delete page follows this pattern: `dashboard/delete/<id>`. See `admin/views.py` below for more details.

While the system works, the problem I have is that a user can simply skip the confirmation page by typing `dashboard/delete/<id>`, where `<id>` is substituted by an actual item id, into the address bar.

**QUESTIONS**

Is there a way to prevent users from accessing `dashboard/delete/<id>` unless they first go to `dashboard/confirm-delete/<id>` (the confirmation screen)? Alternatively, is my approach wrong and is there a better one available?

**CURRENT CODE:**

Function in my `dashboard.html` page called when a row is selected and the delete button is pressed:

```
$('#remove').click(function () {
  var id = getId();
  window.location.href="/dashboard/confirm-delete" + $.trim(id);
  });
```

Confirm button in `confirm-delete.html` (the delete confirmation page):

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url_for('admin.delete_item', id=item.id) }}" role="button">Confirm Delete</a>
```

My `admins/views.py`:

```
@admin_blueprint.route('dashboard/confirm-delete/<id>')
@login_required
@groups_required(['admin'})
def confirm_delete_item(id)
  item = Item.query.get_or_404(id)
  return render_template('admin/confirm-delete.html', item=item, title="Delete Item")

@admin_blueprint.route('dashboard/delete/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@groups_required(['admin'})
def delete_item(id)
  item = Item.query.get_or_404(id)
  db.session.delete(item)
  db.commit()
  return redirect(url_for('home.homepage'))
```

**SOLUTION**

Based on the answer marked as accepted I solved the problem as follows:

First, I created a new form to handle the `Submit` button in the `confirm-delete.html` page:

`admin/forms.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField

class DeleteForm(FlaskForm):
  submit = SubmitField('Confirm')
```

I substituted the `Confirm Button` code with the following to `confirm-delete.html`:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Finally, I merged both of the functions in `app/views.py` as follows:

```
@admin_blueprint.route('dashboard/confirm-delete/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@groups_required(['admin'})
def confirm_delete_item(id)
  form = DeleteForm()
  item = Item.query.get_or_404(id)
  if form.validate_on_submit():  
    if form.submit.data:
      db.session.delete(item)
      db.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('home.homepage'))
  return render_template('admin/confirm-delete.html', item=item, form=form, title="Delete Item")
```

This way, a user can't bypass the delete confirmation screen by typing a specific link in the address bar, plus it simplifies the code.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind for me would be setting a cookie on the page where the delete button lives, and then checking for that cookie on the confirmation page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, one way of solving your problem is checking for a certain cookie as the user sends a request. But personally I would not recommend this method, because such cookies can very likely be compromised unless you come up with some sort of hashing algorithm to hash the cookie values and check them in some way.

To my mind, the most easy, secure and natural way of doing it is protecting `/delete` route with CSRF-token. You can implement it with **Flask_WTF** extension.
In a word, you have to create something like `DeleteForm`, then you put `{{form.csrf_token}}` in your `confirm-delete.html`and validate it in `delete_view()` with `form.validate_on_submit()`

Check out their docs:
http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html
http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem I had implementing form verification with CSRF was that I still had to somehow pass the `form` object from one view to another. Therefore, I decided to merge both views (which in the end turned out better than my initial approach). I've edited my question to include the solution I used. Thanks!

Comment: @nessus_pp I was struggling with this for hours and read this comment. Essentially, my pseudo-code was `if form.validate_on_submit(): redirect to the other route`. After reading your comment, I changed it to `if form.validate_on_submit(): just render the other route's template directly instead of redirecting`. This worked perfectly, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

I would make the delete page POST-only. The browser may skip a GET request or try it many times, you have no control over it. A crawler could follow an anonymous delete link and delete all your wiki articles. A browser prefetcher could prefetch a logout link.

REST purists would insist you use GET, POST, DELETE and PUT methods for their intended purposes.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server

So,

In HTML

```
<form action='/dashboard/delete/{{id}}' method='post'>
```

In Flask

```
@app.route('/dashboard/delete/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete(id):
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative. I ended up combining both of my view functions so I kept the `methods=['GET', 'POST']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mistake in parenthesis.
@groups_required(['admin'})

Shouldn't it be ??
@groups_required(['admin'])